# Calculate fixed sum of array if some values changed

Tags: arrays, excel

Say we are given a vector which sums to 1. Assume if values are higher than n, we maximize these to value n, and we want to make the rest of the numbers such that the sum equals 1 again. I.e. the other values need to (potentially) increase. 
 The other values must increase evenly (by the same factor)

Is there an easy way in excel to do this?

```
Ex. let n = 0.25
0.077331613     0.077331613
0.237037801     0.237037801
0.341441747     0.25
0.336289699     0.25
0.007899139     0.007899139
```

The second vector does not sum to 1, and we need to make sure it does without changing elements of value 0.25.

Comment: You might be able to do this with a long, complicated array formula that is very calculation intensive (and risks circular references) but VBA would make the iterations easier.

Comment: I've got very little experience with VBA or programming in general. Could you give a short example of how I could code this?

Comment: Have you already considered using the solver? This allows you to modify one cell in order to achieve a formula result, but as I say, this only applies on 1 cell only, which means in your example that one of the values would be adapted, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I agree that the required formulas are "long" and "complicated", nor "calculation intensive" :-).

Assuming your original values are in A2:A6, and your choice of n, e.g. 0.25, in C1, then, in B2:

`=IF(A2>=C$1,C$1,A2*(1-C$1*COUNTIF(A$2:A$6,">="&C$1))/SUMIF(A$2:A$6,"<"&C$1))`

Copy down to B6.

Regards

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed :)

Comment: Apparently I missed something in the translation. A3 (0.237037801
) becomes 0.367764398 which is larger than *n* and must be recalculated (with all other values recalculated based on the new value). That might present one of the complications I referred to. But if 0.367764398 is a valid answer, then I guess I was just reading too much into it.

Comment: @Jeeped Not sure I understand. The initial IF clause in my formula means that no one value can be greater than n.

Comment: But the *adjusted* value can be. See in my image with your formula in B3.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point, and one which would benefit from the OP clarifying.

Comment: That's where the iteration I thought would complicate things came in but the OP has accepted your answer so I guess it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this UDF while the other answer was accepted so I'll post it here for future viewers of this thread.

Tap Alt+F11 then Alt+I, M and paste the following into a module code sheet. Tap Alt+Q to return to your worksheet.

```
Function udf_vector_elements(rng As Range, elm As Long, n As Double, ttl As Double)
    Dim dTTL As Double
    Dim v As Long, vELMs As Variant
    Dim awf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim iSAFETY As Long, iLESS As Long, dFUDGE As Double

    Set awf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    ReDim vELMs(1 To rng.Cells.Count)

    'safety for not enough elements × n < ttl
    If rng.Cells.Count * n < ttl Then
        udf_vector_elements = "never enough"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'seed the solution array
    For v = LBound(vELMs) To UBound(vELMs)
        If rng.Cells(v).Value2 < n Then
            vELMs(v) = rng.Cells(v).Value2
            iLESS = iLESS + 1
        Else
            vELMs(v) = n
        End If
    Next v

    'safety for sum(elements) > ttl
    If awf.Sum(vELMs) > ttl Then
        udf_vector_elements = "already too much"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'get to work
    Do While Round(awf.Sum(vELMs), 6) < ttl
        dFUDGE = (ttl - Round(awf.Sum(vELMs), 6)) / iLESS
        iLESS = 0
        For v = LBound(vELMs) To UBound(vELMs)
            vELMs(v) = Round(awf.Min(vELMs(v) + dFUDGE, n), 6)
            iLESS = iLESS - (vELMs(v) <> n)
        Next v
    Loop

    'debug.print
    dTTL = awf.Sum(vELMs)

    Set awf = Nothing

    'return the individual adjusted vector array element
    udf_vector_elements = vELMs(elm)

End Function
```

Use as any other native worksheet function.

> =udf_vector_elements(*<vector_values>, <element_returned>, <max_n>, <target_total>*)

In the below image in C2 as,

```
=udf_vector_elements(A$2:A$6, ROW(1:1), E$1, 1)
```

[image: udf_vector_elements]

Fill down as necessary.